# -Dspring.profiles.active not recognized under condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el, system-properties

I have passed `-Dspring.profiles.active` as a system property:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>#{'dev' or 'sit' or 'qa'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}')  ? 'classpath:process${spring.profiles.active}.properties' : 'classpath:env/cfg/process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties'}
      </value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

If I pass **dev** in `spring.profiles.active` the condition should pass but it is actuallay failing.

But it gets updated successfully with `Properties` named *process-dev.properties*.

Could someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Why are you using *XML* configuration already and not *Java* annotated one?

Answer (score 2):

You should change it to `'dev'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}') or 'sit'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}') or 'qa'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}')`

Comment: 'dev'.equals('${spring.profiles.active} - the value is not getting

Comment: The Value get not updated. 'dev'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}'). It returns false. But i am passing -Dspring.profiles.active=dev. It must return true

Comment: Can you tell us *exactly* what you are typing on the terminal @Anto?

Comment: I passed -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in argument and application.properties. I have to set these values based on environment .                                              <value>#{'dev' =='${spring.profiles.active}'  ? 'classpath:process${spring.profiles.active}.properties' : 'classpath:env/process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties'} . The value update successfully with properties file name but the condition getting failed beacuse condition level the value is not passing(#{('${spring.profiles.active}'=='dev')?)

Comment: I want the text you entered EXACTLY. e.g. *java -jar anto.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev*. Just write here the whole command as you write it.

Comment: java -Xms256m -Xmx512m --Dlogging.config=log4j2-spring.xml -Dspring.profiles.active="dev" -Dloader.path="config,config" -jar lib/process.jar. But how the file Name got updated with value. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to skip the quotes from dev: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: still not running

Comment: Ah also you may have missed a dash here: `'classpath:process${spring.profiles.active}.properties'`. Probably you meant `'classpath:process-${spring.profiles.active}.properties'`

Comment: #{'dev'.equals('${spring.profiles.active}')  This is the problem. spring.profiles.active didnt get any value . But 'classpath:process${spring.profiles.active}.properties' this is successfully updated